# Query expression throws usupported data type in pipelinebuffer

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, script-component

Having a script component that transforms and push an update to CRM 2015.
the package throws an error:

[image]

After a long investigation I found that the line with QueryExpression from the SDK throws the error, I mean When it is commented the execution continues.

[image]

On the other hand, When I execute the Data flow task alone it does not throw the error.
the SDK for CRM 2015 is already used in other scriptcomponents whithotu any problem.

Have you any idea about this problem.

Comment: What are you doing with the QueryExpression? Are you adding it to the pipeline? If so, evaluate the length of the resulting string. If it's over 4k, then it needs to go into the pipeline buffer as a DT_NTEXT type. In the Input/Output tab, on the Output Buffer, find the definition of your column and look at the type and length to find this info

Comment: I don't have any output. The query expression(SDK) helps to fetch data from Dynamics CRM. With the SDK I'am fetching and then updating. no data added to the pipeline